# TypeORM gives me an error about a null value in a column violating a not-null constraint; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am working with TypeORM to try to make a task that has an associated entry for its owning committee, its related committees, its project lead, and employee entries.

I am expecting to see a passing unit test that executes this line without complaint:

```
const taskDetails: TaskDetails = {
            title: "Baz Creation",
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            committeeId: newCommittee1.committeeId,
        };
        const taskPayload1 = {
            committees: [newCommittee1, newCommittee2],
            projectLead: newUser1,
            membersToAdd: [newUser1, newUser2, newUser3],
        };
        await taskDAO.createTask(newCommittee1, taskDetails, taskPayload1.committees, taskPayload1.projectLead, taskPayload1.membersToAdd);
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
   QueryFailedError: null value in column "memberUserId" of relation "tasks_for_member" violates not-null constraint

      at PostgresQueryRunner.query (src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
      at InsertQueryBuilder.execute (src/query-builder/InsertQueryBuilder.ts:163:33)
      at SubjectExecutor.executeInsertOperations (src/persistence/SubjectExecutor.ts:428:42)
      at SubjectExecutor.execute (src/persistence/SubjectExecutor.ts:137:9)
      at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts:197:21)
      at TaskDAO.createTask (src/db/dao/task.dao.ts:49:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/dbUtil/purgeDb.test.ts:132:9)
```

It's obviously saying something like "you know this join table is supposed to have an entry in it right?" yet somehow I'm not telling TypeORM to make that entry correctly.

I don't get it though:

(a) TypeORM should create the entries in the join table for me.
(b) I have every relation in my db set to be nullable. See below.

Here are my related Task and Member entities:

Task.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Task {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    taskId: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    description: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    status: Role;

    @ManyToMany(() => Member, (member: Member) => member.tasks, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "task_leads" })
    leads?: Member[]; // this might be the source of the issue

    @ManyToMany(() => Member, (member: Member) => member.tasks, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "task_members" })
    members?: Member[]; // this might be the source of the issue

    @ManyToOne(() => Committee, committee => committee.inChargeOf, { nullable: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: "owning_committee" }) // tried adding this; didnt help
    ownedBy?: Committee;

    @ManyToMany(() => Committee, committee => committee.tasks, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "task_committees" })
    relatedCommittees?: Committee[];
}
```

Member.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class Member {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    userId: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    displayName?: string;


    @ManyToMany(() => Committee, committee => committee.members, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "member_of" })
    memberOf?: Committee[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Committee, committee => committee.leads, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "lead_of" })
    leadOf?: Committee[];

    @OneToMany(() => Committee, committee => committee.head, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    headOf?: Committee;

    @ManyToMany(() => Task, (task: Task) => task.members, { nullable: true, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinTable({ name: "tasks_for_member" }) // this might be the source of the issue
    tasks?: Task[];
}
```

Here's how I'm creating the task:

```
public async createTask(
        headCommittee: Committee,
        taskDetails: TaskDetails,
        relatedCommittees: Committee[] | null,
        projectLead: Member | null,
        membersToAdd: Member[] | null,
    ): Promise<Task> {
        try {
            const task = new Task();
            task.title = taskDetails.title;
            task.startDate = taskDetails.startDate;
            task.endDate = taskDetails.endDate;
            task.ownedBy = headCommittee;
            if (projectLead) {
                task.leads = [projectLead];
            }
            if (membersToAdd) {
                task.members = membersToAdd;
                // // QueryFailedError: null value in column "memberUserId" of relation "tasks_for_member" violates not-null constraint
                for (const member of membersToAdd) { // this loop didn't help me
                    member.tasks = [task];
                    this.memberRepository.save(member);
                } 
            }
            if (relatedCommittees) {
                task.relatedCommittees = relatedCommittees;
            }
            console.log(task, "36rm");
            await this.taskRepository.save(task);
            return task;
        } catch (error: unknown) {
            // handle
        }
    }
```

I really expect the line `task.members = membersToAdd;` to handle this for me. It's TypeScript so all the arguments to the function are what they say they are. I don't get it.

edit: I did excise some columns of the Member and Task table for brevity. The task dao method shows what fields the task really has.

edit2: commenting this out makes the error go away, but I need the block to work!

```
     if (membersToAdd) {
         task.members = membersToAdd;
     }
```

edit3: I recreated the "relevant" code in a separate project and, this code as I show it works there! Hence I am failing to discover the actual source of the issue in the code I posted.

edit4: found the source of the bug though i dont understand how

in my server.ts file I have

```
import {
    committeeRepository,
    taskRepository,
    memberRepository,
} from "./db/data-source";
// later...
const committeeDAO = new CommitteeDAO(committeeRepository);
const memberDAO = new MemberDAO(memberRepository); // commenting out this & the prior line fixes the bug!
const taskDAO = new TaskDAO(taskRepository, memberDAO, memberRepository);
```

they are exported from `data-source.ts` like this:

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    database: "typeormtest",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [Member, Task, Committee ],
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
});

export const committeeRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Committee);
export const memberRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Member);
export const taskRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Task);
```

at the top of my tests I do similar:

```
const memberDAO = new MemberDAO(memberRepository);
const taskDAO = new TaskDAO(taskRepository, memberDAO, memberRepository);
const committeeDAO = new CommitteeDAO(committeeRepository)
```

I really don't get it, why does that line cause the bug?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had `@JoinTable` marked on both sides of the relationship for Task <=> Committee and Task <=> Member

In fact it's only supposed to be present on *I think* the side that will be -- umm, I lack words, [check the docs here](https://typeorm.io/)

```
@Entity()
export class Album {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(() => Photo, (photo) => photo.albums)
    @JoinTable() // look here
    photos: Photo[]
}

export class Photo {
    // ... other columns

    @ManyToMany(() => Album, (album) => album.photos)
    albums: Album[] // and here -- @JoinTable is NOT present
}
```

```
const photo = new Photo()
photo.name = "Me and Bears"
photo.description = "I am near polar bears"
photo.filename = "photo-with-bears.jpg"
photo.views = 1
photo.isPublished = true
photo.albums = [album1, album2] // and look here - it gets the albums
await AppDataSource.manager.save(photo)
```

`Photo` gets the `JoinTable` because it's what the albums will be attached to. If the photos were going to be attached to albums like `album.photos = [photo1, photo2]` then the `@JoinTable` would be on the other side